# Finding the Dual of a primal LP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Suppose that we have the following primal LP:

$\min z=c^Tu+d^Tv \\
\mbox{s.t.}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  u+Av=b, u\geq 0, v\geq 0$

I want to find the  dual problem of this LP but I am slightly confused as to how I go about doing this?

I know that I first need to get the Lagrangian which is:

$L(u,v,y,s)=(c^Tu+d^Tv)-y^T(u+Av-b)-s^T(u)- q^T(v)$

but now  I am unsure how to get the optimality condition for this by differentiating with respect to what?

Ok so I think that this is actually pretty trivial. We just differentiate w.r.t u then v and set equal to 0 for the optimality condition as follows:

$\nabla_u L(u,v,y,s)=c^T-y^T-s^T-q^T=0$ and $\nabla_v L(u,v,y,s)d^T -y^TA-s^T-q^T=0$

These are now our constraints which if we sub in will give the objective function being $by^T$ and we will be done.

If we finally drop $s,q$ as slack variables we have the following dual:

$$\begin{array}{l l} \max & by^t \\ subject to & y^T-c^T\leq 0 \\ ~ & A^Ty-d^T \leq 0 \\ ~ & y\ \  free \end{array}$$

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are there any dimensions of the matrices (vectors) given ? Since it is a linear problem, I would define the dual problem without using the Langarian.

Comment: @calculus No dimensions given but I don't see why that would be relevant? Also is what I have done not correct, I think I have it?